# R programming language, where clause

Tags: r

Within the R programming language, is it possible to use a where clause within ggplot?  If not, then within the R language to allow me to use a where clause?  For example, using the diamonds table can I only select records that the cut = "Good".  Cut is a field in the Diamond table.  The Cut field can equal "Fair", "Good", Very Good", "Premium", and "Ideal".

```
diamonds[1:5,]
#   carat     cut   color  clarity    depth  table   price         x    y    z
# 1  0.23   Ideal       E      SI2     61.5     55     326      3.95 3.98 2.43
```

I want to use some type of conditional statement against a CSV read file.  But to keep my example simple, I using the diamond table as a typical example of my problem.  I want to filter cut = "Good" but to include fields related to the records = "Good".

Thank you for any help to my question.

Comment: what about `ggplot(subset(diamonds,cut=="Good")) + ...` ?

Comment: if you prefer SQL syntax you might look at the `sqldf` package.

Comment: just don't use "where," it is not needed. the bigger picture is that you need subset methods which r has in spades: `subset`,`[`,`[[`,`$`, etc

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `subset` function to filter rows from a data frame:

```
goodDiamods <- subset(diamonds, cut=='Good')
```

Check: [Quick-R: Subsetting data](http://www.statmethods.net/management/subset.html)

---

Another option is to use the `sqldf` package, and write a "query-like" expression:

```
library(sqldf)
goodDiamonds <- sqldf("select * from diamonds where cut='Good'")
```

Comment: Thank you for the help and suggestion on using Quick-R Subsetting data.